# Calculating time worked during lunch break - shift workers

Tags: sql

I am trying to create a query that will calculate the hours worked by employees working during a night shift, ie. from 18:00 to 3:00AM the next morning.  They are given a break between 10PM and 11PM everyday. The problem is creating the Calc_last_Clock_Time.  I cant seem to get the last clock, becasue when I use "MAX(ClockOut)" it gives me the last clock for that day.  The last clock will actually be on the following morning at 3:35:10.

If i take clockins like this:

```
Name         ClockTime      Direction
Person A      18:00:15         IN
Person A      10:05:10         OUT
Person A      10:35:45         IN
Person A      03:35:10         OUT
```

I need to get the person's first and last clockin for the shift, as well as how many hours he worked.  I also need to know how long he worked during his lunchbreak.  I have the following code at the moment.  Can anyone help me to get this working?

```
; WITH emp_clock AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT FullName = Pers.[Name] + ' ' + Pers.Surname,
                RowNo = row_number() OVER (partition BY Pers.Personel_ID
            ORDER BY C.ClockTime),
                ClockDate = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, C.ClockTime), 0),
                DayAdj = CASE WHEN Default_Shift_End < Default_Shift_Start THEN 0
        ELSE 1 END,
                ClockTime    = RC.ClockTime,
                DirectionName = Dir.[Name],
                ShiftRuleGroup = Rules.[Name],
                ShiftStartTime = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Rules.Default_Shift_Start, 108),
                ShiftEndTime = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), 
                Rules.Default_Shift_End,               
                Rules_SRBreak    = SRBreak.[Name],
                BreakStartTime    = SRBreak.SR_Break_StartTime,
                BreakEndTime    = SRBreak.SR_Break_EndTime
        FROM Personnel Pers
                INNER JOIN ClockIns C ON Pers.Personel_ID = C.Person_ID
                INNER JOIN Direction Dir ON    RC.Direction_ID = Dir.Direction_ID
                INNER JOIN EmpShiftGroup ON Pers.Personel_ID =  
                EmpShiftGroup.Employee_ID
                INNER JOIN Rules Rules ON Rules.Rules_ID = EmpShiftGroup.Rules_ID
                INNER JOIN SDay ON Rules.Rules_ID = SDay.Rules_ID
                LEFT OUTER JOIN SRBreak ON SRBreak.SRDay_ID = SRDay.SRDay_ID),  timelog
            AS  (
    SELECT
               FullName = COALESCE(ci.FullName, co.FullName), 
              ClockTime = COALESCE(ci.ClockTime, co.ClockTime), 
ShiftRuleGroup = COALESCE(ci.RULE, co.RULE),  
ShiftStartTime = COALESCE(ci.ShiftStartTime, co.ShiftStartTime), 
ShiftEndTime    = COALESCE(ci.ShiftEndTime, co.ShiftEndTime), 
                    SRBreak = COALESCE(ci.SRBreak, co.SRBreak),
                    BreakStartTime = COALESCE(ci.BreakStartTime, co.BreakStartTime),
                    BreakEndTime = COALESCE(ci.BreakEndTime,    co.BreakEndTime),
                    ClockIn = COALESCE(ci.ClockTime, co.ClockDate - co.DayAdj + co.ShiftStartTime),
                    ClockOut = COALESCE(co.ClockTime, ci.ClockDate + ci.DayAdj + ci.ShiftEndTime)
            FROM emp_clock ci  FULL OUTER JOIN emp_clock co ON    ci.Personel_ID    = co.Personel_ID
                AND ci.RowNo = co.RowNo - 1  
                AND co.ClockTime < DATEADD(DAY, 1, ci.ClockDate) + ci.ShiftStartTime
            WHERE NOT (ci.DirectionName IS NULL
                    AND co.DirectionName = 'IN')  
                AND NOT (ci.DirectionName = 'OUT'    
                    AND    co.DirectionName IS NULL)  
                AND (ci.DirectionName = 'IN'
                    OR ci.DirectionName IS NULL)), detail AS (
        SELECT FullName, ClockTime, ClockIn,ClockOut, ShiftStartTime, ShiftEndTime,  BreakStartTime, BreakEndTime,
                    TimeBeforeShiftStart = CASE WHEN ClockIn - DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, ClockIn), 0) <  ShiftStartTime THEN ClockIn - DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, ClockIn), 0) END,
                    TimeBeforeShiftEnd = CASE WHEN ClockIn - DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, ClockIn), 0) <  ShiftStartTime THEN ShiftStartTime END,
                    TimeAfterShiftStart = casee WHEN ClockOut - DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, ClockOut), 0) >  ShiftEndTime THEN ShiftEndTime END,
                TimeAfterShiftEnd = CASE WHEN ClockOut - DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, ClockOut), 0) >  ShiftEndTime THEN ClockOut - DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, ClockOut), 0) END  
        FROM timelog),
                summary AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT FullName, ClockDate = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, ClockIn), 0),111), MIN(ClockTime) AS Calc_First_Clock,
   Calc_Last_Clock = ????,
TotalWorkHours = CAST(SUM(DATEDIFF(minute, ClockIn, ClockOut) / 60.0) AS DECIMAL(4,2)),
                    Before_Shift = CAST(ISNULL(SUM(DATEDIFF(minute, TimeBeforeShiftStart, TimeBeforeShiftEnd)), 0) / 60.0 AS DECIMAL(4,2)),
                    After_Shift = CAST(ISNULL(SUM(DATEDIFF(minute, TimeAfterShiftStart, TimeAfterShiftEnd)), 0) / 60.0 AS DECIMAL(4,2))  
            FROM detail
            GROUP BY  DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, ClockTime), 0),  Personel_ID, FullName, ClockIn,ClockOut, ShiftStartTime, ShiftEndTime,  BreakStartTime, BreakEndTime )  
    SELECT * FROM summary
```

Comment: What is the problem with the current code? That's a rather large amount of code; can you possibly reduce it down to the particularly problematic part(s)?

Comment: You've got several issues here with the complexity of that SQL. I suggest you break it down to the smallest bit of SQL possible and ask again, it is just too much for someone to quickly help with. Also, I suggest you look at another way of solving the issue and get a copy of SQL for Smarties By Celko http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Hi9fMnOoRtAC&pg=PA120&lpg=PA120

Comment: You should strip your code on concentrate on the problem.

Comment: I would also recommend providing some sample DDL & data to make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: +1 on the DDL & data.  Your next problem will be dirty data.  I've worked with this kind of data before, and people *never* punch in and out consistently.  You'll need to build rules in to catch when someone punches in for work, forgets to punch out for their break, punches back in, then punches out at the end of the day.

Comment: How did this question get four upvotes?

Comment: @configurator the [Vox Populi](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/1108/vox-populi) badge, how else?

Comment: +1 for schema details - Whilst a certain amount may be inferred from the statement you provide, knowing whether the schema is fixed (we cannot change its design as part of an answer) and if so what the current schema is, would certainly help.

Comment: Maybe I am naive, but if you can change the schema, do so. Adding an id to a collection of IN/Outs making a shift for an individual would simplify your entire query. The "container" for the employee's hours would be the shift and not the day. From my experience I find that (statistically speaking) the hairier the query gets, the less likely the underlying data is correctly normalized.

Comment: There is a good question in here; as others said, just pare it down a little! And supply some business rules! If a worker does a night shift followed by a day shift back to back, how do we know when the night shift ends? E.g., do we assume punching out for more than two hours means that shift is over?